# Is it possible to have multiple rows with SELECT FROM DUAL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I have something like

```
SELECT (1, 2, 4542, 342) FROM DUAL;
```

and get it like this?

```
  |  1    |
  |  2    |
  |  4542 |
  |  342  |
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Before 23c:** Instead of `DUAL`, select from a pre-built collection to return multiple rows. This solution has a small syntax, avoids type conversions, and avoids potentially slow recursive queries. But it's good to understand the other solutions as well, since they are all useful in different contexts.

```
select column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 4542, 342));
```

Note that the `TABLE()` operator is optional in modern versions of Oracle, and it is only required in older versions.

---

**23c or later:** The table values constructor, `VALUES`, provides an easier way to return multiple rows. This feature does not require any predefined collection, and it can also be used to return multiple columns per row if desired.

```
select * from (values (1), (2), (4542), (342)) a (id);
```

Comment: this is just brilliant!

Answer (score 11):

Well if `(1, 2, 4542, 342)`  were a string you could do this:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT '1, 2, 4542, 342' as str 
    FROM DUAL
)
select regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,level) 
from cte
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
/
```

Answer (score 8):

No.  `dual` has just one row, but you can use `union all`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4542 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 342 FROM DUAL;
```

This is just one way to generate a table "on-the-fly" in Oracle.

Answer (score 7):

```
select decode(level,3,4542,4,342,level) lvl from dual connect by level <= 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Dual table is basically a dummy table which is having one row and one column and is exists in sys schema

`SELECT (1,2, 4542, 342) FROM DUAL;`

This will give you an error because you have passed more than one column in this table. 1,2,4542,342 treated as separate column. Try the below Query:-

`SELECT ('1,2, 4542, 342') FROM DUAL;`

'1,2, 4542, 342' will treated as a single string.

For your required output we can use **UNION ALL** operator. Try the below query:-

`SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4542 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 342 FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 2):

Dual table can have multiple rows and multiple columns, for example =>

```
SQL> select 1, 'john' from dual
  2  union
  3  select 2, 'smith' from dual;

         1 'JOHN
---------- -----
         1 john
         2 smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Other example whit **alias**:

SELECT column_value as xvalue
FROM sys.odcinumberlist ( 1, 2, 4542, 342 ) ;

Comment: **Whit char:**

SELECT column_value as charts FROM TABLE(**SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST** ( '1w', '2', '4542', '342' )  )  ;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).